# Textarea not rendering correctly in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textarea

I have application where I change text of textarea using javascript. When I change it I can see that in developers tools it has changed but it's not rendered correctly.

Here is the link to image. On the right there is developer's console where you can see that value of textare is "[ ]" but the displayed value is different.

This issue is present in Firefox and Chrome but strangely not in Microsoft edge.

https://pasteboard.co/JnJMIhs.png
[image: test1]
[image: test2]
[image: test3]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the code for your Javascript and form...

Comment: Try this, enter something, lose the focus from the textarea(click somewhere else) and get its value in console via js. Also, see if you get that textarea Dom element's value via value() or text().

Comment: @dalelandry I added ref pictures

Answer (score 0):

if you see for textarea innerHTML is what was rendered already when this DOM element loaded with document. Whereas value is the current text (live value) of the textarea.[image]